# removing anything later than a specific date

Tags: python, pandas

```
name  date           ID1     check
John  2008-01-01      1       yes        
John  2009-01-01      2       NAN
John  2010-01-01      3       NAN
Cindy 2012-01-01      4       yes
Lisa  2010-01-03      5       yes
Cindy 2010-05-08      6       yes
Lisa  2003-02-03      7       NAN
Lisa  2001-02-01      8       yes
```

I have this dataset which I need to clean up a little bit.

- If check is 'yes', I will treat the date as the most current date and remove anything after this date for each individual.
- If one person has multiple date with a check 'yes', I pick the earliest date
- Do a count for ID1, and find all that fits prior criteria

The return should look like this:

```
name  date           ID1     check
John  2008-01-01      1       yes        
Cindy 2010-05-08      2       yes
Lisa  2001-02-01      3       yes
```

The logic is a bit too complicated, anyone has any suggestions on how to work with this.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a coding service; since you didn't provide any code, we'll just be content with logic.

Let's look at this from the "keep" rather than the "remove" side.  For your application, the logic is simpler.  Also, that's the way a filter works.

The steps I see are

1. Filter for `yes` values.
2. `groupby` the `name` column.
3. Sort by date, ascending.
4. Truncate each group to the first element (row) only.  This is a simple slice.
5. Reapply your `ID` assignment.

You should now have the desired data frame.  Can you take it from there?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `.drop_duplicates(keep='first')`

First you have to sort the df though

```
df[df['check']=='yes'].sort_values(by=['date']).drop_duplicates(['name', 'check'], keep='first')

    name    date    ID1 check
7   Lisa    2001-02-01  8   yes
0   John    2008-01-01  1   yes
5   Cindy   2010-05-08  6   yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Setup:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])  # Ensure Date column is datetime
```

Try dropping rows based on NaN values in check using [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html#pandas-dataframe-dropna)

```
filtered = df.dropna(subset=['check']).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Then use [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) to count the number of ID1 for each name in the filtered frame.

```
filtered['ID1'] = filtered.groupby('name')['ID1'].transform('count')
```

`filtered`:

```
    name       date  ID1 check
0   John 2008-01-01    1   yes
1  Cindy 2012-01-01    2   yes
2   Lisa 2010-01-03    2   yes
3  Cindy 2010-05-08    2   yes
4   Lisa 2001-02-01    2   yes
```

Option 1: [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html#pandas-dataframe-sort-values) + [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html#pandas-dataframe-drop-duplicates)

```
output = (
    filtered.sort_values('date')  # Make Sure min date is first
        .drop_duplicates('name')  # Remove duplicate name rows (keeping first)
        .sort_index()  # Sort Values by index (Restore order)
)
```

`output`:

```
    name       date  ID1 check
0   John 2008-01-01    1   yes
3  Cindy 2010-05-08    2   yes
4   Lisa 2001-02-01    2   yes
```

Option 2: [`groupby.idxmin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin.html#pandas-core-groupby-dataframegroupby-idxmin) to get the indexes of where the min values are

```
output = filtered.loc[
    filtered.groupby('name')['date'].idxmin()
].sort_index()  # Sort Values by index (Restore order)
```

`output`:

```
    name       date  ID1 check
0   John 2008-01-01    1   yes
3  Cindy 2010-05-08    2   yes
4   Lisa 2001-02-01    2   yes
```